# Call a function on application startup in react

Tags: reactjs, constructor

I'm trying to call a function from application startup.  The function reads data from JSON via dataVar (set elsewhere) and tries to load it into {items} for further consumption:

```
const dataVar = JSONStuff;    
class Global extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            items: []
        }

        this.init();

    } 

    // componentDidMount() {
    // This doesn't work either!
    //  this.init();
    // }

    init() {
        let { items } = dataVar;
        this.setState({items});
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Global">
                    <Gallery items={this.state.items}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Then in Gallery.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Gallery extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>gallery:</h3>
                {
                    this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
                        let {title} = item.name;
                        return (
                            <div key={index}>{title}</div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

export default Gallery;

Not sure why Global can't call a function inside of itself.  I've tried with and without "this."  I either get error to where the app won't complile or I get:

```
"Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op."
```

Comment: Did you remove `this.init()` from your constructor when you tried it from the `componentDidMount` method?

Comment: Do you load data inside dataVar ?

Comment: @SterlingArcher yes

Comment: @Aaqib, yes I do.

Comment: Are you trying to create Global manually with `new Global(...)`? How is it called?

Comment: didnt bind the function

Comment: Joel I edited the question to answer your question.  @Omar, I tried that too, but would you mind giving me an example of specifically what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's a warning, you probably better not call `setState` in `componentDidMount`.

My suggestion 1: assign value to state in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    query: '',
    items: dataVar.items,
  };
}
```

Suggestion 2:

Do inside the componentWillReceiveProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const { dataVar: items } = nextProps; // pass dataVar as props
  this.setState({
    items,
  });
}
```

Plus try to debug your props and pay attention on your console for errors.

Comment: That's better, but now throwing an error in Gallery.js, for let { title } = item.name:

Gallery.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: you should debug that and do a check if item is undefined or not

Comment: It's actually the "You should debug" comment that solved the issue.  The JSON was formed improperly.  Would you mind maybe just adding that to your answer?  Apologies for what turned out to be an AWFUL question.  <hangs head in shame>